# Get HTML from Ajax call

Tags: ajax

Been a while since I done this but I must be doing something wrong.

I am using asp.netcore 2.1
I have a view with a button on it.
The button makes an ajax call to get the contents of a html page.

But, despite triple checking the uri the console error tells me it cannot find the page with a 404 error.
The html page is just a div structure.

this is my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Helper/Dialogs/CreateClient.html',
    dataType : 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        dialogObj.setProperties(
            { content: data }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you certain that your specified url path is correct? Check spelling for lower and upper cases as well, as well as file extension.

Comment: @Martin I said i tripled checked it all.

Comment: Do you load your html into a specific element, such as a div or something? The general notation I see is `success: function(html) {` instead of `success: function(data) {`, and the a specified element like `$('#myDiv').html(html);` within the success function.

Comment: @martin what does that have to do with the ajax call?

Comment: My initial thought is that the path is wrong, because it's a 404 error, but you insist on that not being the case. You say you triple checked. I just wanted to make sure that you checked firstly the path, secondly the spelling of the path, thirdly the file extension of the file you are trying to retrieve. Could your issue potentially be that you don't have *"permission"* to access the specified path? I mean I'm just spitballing here. #rubberDucking.

Comment: @martin I really d appreciate your commitment to help but you are asking really basic questions,   There are lots of obscure reasons for a 404 error and your suggestion of case sensitivity is not correct. It does not matter when making an ajax call. Nor is where is where I am potentially loading the html into.  I have posted my own answer. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case people get tripped up by this I was storing my html page in a sub-folder off the root off  my solution. Because I am using asp.net core all 'adhoc' content has to be under the wwwroot folder in the solution.

It is obvious to me now but I thought I would post my answer in case people find it useful.

Comment: So basically it was because you don't have access to the specified path, because the apache server is not allowed to access *user* directories. Also starting with `/` when declaring a path means you begin from *root*.

Comment: NO!  I am not using apache. It has NOTHING to do with permission,  It has everything all to do with mappings. I am using asp.net core as I SPECIFIED in my original question. jeezzz